# Adding new function causes memory corruption

Tags: c, memory

My problem is in C programming, this is a weird issue, when a function will be added in a particular source file(.C), this causes a problem to our firmware. Is it possible that a new function could cause memory corruption?
Note: The function that was newly added was not called by any thread by any means. This was confirmed by adding a code that causes the function to throw a segmentation fault. This is in linux environment.
What are other ways to debug this problem?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My guess is you have memory corruption problem elsewhere in the code. It happens to work until you perturb things by adding another function. Do the usual things to check for memory errors like running `valgrind`. Without seeing some code, can't say anything more.

Comment: @RSahu - it is difficult to post codes because this is a confidential code.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by pretty much anything. The most likely causes:

- Somewhere in your program there could be a bug which invokes undefined behavior. It has been dormant until now and the program seems to work, but when memory layout changed, the behavior changes.
  There are multiple cases of undefined behavior that could cause this, the most likely ones being pointers pointing at wrong addresses or array out-of-bounds access.
- The new function caused you to run out of stack memory and you got a stack overflow. Particularly likely if the function added an extra level of depth in the call stack. If you never call the function, this wouldn't be an issue. (But if you never call the function, how can you tell it was actually linked to begin with?)

There is no universal way to find every case of undefined behavior in your program. It is not really meaningful for anyone to post a general answer about how to debug any generic program crash... Use trace if available, if not check the call stack upon the crash and find the crashing function and so on.